# Laptop in cargo hold insurance coverage

Tags: air-travel, insurance, electronic-items

I will be travelling from Belgrade in Serbia to London UK in a few weeks. There is a stopover at Instanbul in Turkey.

Given the recent laptop travel ban, I probably be required to put my laptop in cargo. I am wondering whether anyone knows if it is possible to insure the laptop against damage or theft while on the cargo of the plane.

Comment: Check travel insurances - they usually cover lost and damaged luggage.

Comment: I edited this slightly, for the question but to remove the request for recommendations, as that asks for opinions, which the TSE format doesn't permit.

Comment: what laptop travel ban ?

Comment: I never know about anything!  :)

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative option. According to comments on FlyerTalk, you can hand your laptop to Turkish at your gate in Istanbul and they were put it in special suitcases designed to protect such devices in the hold. You collect next to baggage reclaim at your destination. However, enough people now do this that you have to queue to deposit devices.

See: http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/turkish-airlines-miles-smiles/1830818-electronics-ban-us-uk-bound-flights-12.html